# Object detection deep learning network detecting whole image as class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to detect objects in technical drawings. As I am new to Pytorch, and do not fully know the API, I am having trouble training a deep neural netowork for my project. I am using a faster R-CNN for the test. Iniatializing without weights and instead training from scracth using my own data that was labelled with Label Studio.

Below is the code I have tried and have been adapting based on the documentation. The num_classes are 9 classes in my objects plus the background.

The problem is that the output only contains one or two predicted boxes, and worse the full image is detected as an object. Can you spot any problems here?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have tried and implemented the network that at least can be trained and shows a reduction in loss.

```
start_time = time.time()
model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=None, num_classes=10)

# Construct optimizer and learning rate scheduler

params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=1e-6, momentum=0, weight_decay=0.0005)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=0.1)

NUM_EPOCHS = 6

# Store losses to plot loss in train and validation
loss_progress = []

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    print(f"Beginning epoch: {epoch}")
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss = 0.0

    loss_dict = model(images, targets)
    losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
    losses.backward()

test_image = images[15]

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    results = model(torch.unsqueeze(test_image, 0))

    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()

    total_loss += losses.item()

    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{NUM_EPOCHS}], Loss: {losses.item():.4f}")

    loss_progress.append(losses.item())
```

This is the minimal data processing pipeline I require and can show:

```
images = []
images_dir = os.path.join(root_data, "images")

for item in os.listdir(images_dir):
    item_path = os.path.join(images_dir, item)
    if os.path.isfile(item_path) and str.endswith(item_path, ".png"):
        image = Image.open(item_path)
        image = image.convert("L")
        image = datapoints.Image(image, dtype=torch.float32)
        image = F.normalize(image, mean=0.9619, std=0.1660)
        images.append(image)

# Load and process annotations

targets = []
annotations_dir = os.path.join(root_data, "annotations")
for xml_file in os.listdir(annotations_dir):
    xml_path = os.path.join(annotations_dir, xml_file)
    tree = ET.parse(xml_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    boxes = []
    labels = []

    for object_element in root.findall("object"):
        label = object_element.find("name").text
        xmin = int(object_element.find(".//xmin").text)
        ymin = int(object_element.find(".//ymin").text)
        xmax = int(object_element.find(".//xmax").text)
        ymax = int(object_element.find(".//ymax").text)

        label_encoded = symbols_metadata.get_attribute(label, "value")
        # Boxes in XYHW format
        # box = [xmin, ymin, xmin + xmax, ymin + ymax]
        box = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]

        boxes.append(box)
        labels.append(label_encoded)

    boxes = torch.tensor(data=boxes, dtype=torch.int32)
    labels = torch.tensor(data=labels, dtype=torch.int64)

    targets.append({"boxes": boxes, "labels": labels})
```